# placing multiple imported sheets into different cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to import multiple sheets. Each imported file have 2 columns. I want the first file to be placed on Column A and Column B and the second imported file to be placed on Column C and column D on the same sheet.

The following below is my code to import multiple sheets.

```
Sub ImportFiles()

   'Declare a variable as a FileDialog object.
   Dim fd As FileDialog
   Dim path As String
   Dim filename As String

   
   Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
   Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
   With fd
       .AllowMultiSelect = True
       'Set the initial path to the C:\ drive.
       .InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.path
       'Add a filter that includes  the list.
       .Filters.Clear
       .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.txt", 1
       'The user pressed the button.
       If .Show = -1 Then
       
           For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
               path = Left(vrtSelectedItem, InStrRev(vrtSelectedItem, "\"))
               filename = Right(vrtSelectedItem, Len(vrtSelectedItem) - InStrRev(vrtSelectedItem, "\"))
               
               Call Importfile(path, filename)
                                     

           Next vrtSelectedItem
       Else
       End If
   End With

   Set fd = Nothing

End Sub
Sub Importfile(path As String, filename As String)
   'Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Sheet1")).Name = "RawData"
   'ActiveSheet.Name = filename
   On Error Resume Next
   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
       "TEXT;" & path & filename, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
       .Name = filename
       .FieldNames = True
       .RowNumbers = False
       .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
       .PreserveFormatting = True
       .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
       .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
       .SavePassword = False
       .SaveData = False
       .AdjustColumnWidth = False
       .RefreshPeriod = 0
       .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
       .TextFilePlatform = xlWindows
       .TextFileStartRow = 1
       .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
       .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
       .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
       .TextFileOtherDelimiter = vbTab
       .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
       .TextFileThousandsSeparator = " "
       .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
   End With
End Sub
```

I did try to place a for loop after "If .Show =-1 Then," such as

```
Dim FileNames As String
Dim WSNew As Worksheet

For Each filename in FileNames
Set WSNew = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
Next filename
```

but it shows an error such that it cant compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your existing procedure with this one:-

```
Sub Importfile(path As String, filename As String)

    Dim Target      As Range
    Dim C           As Long
    
   'Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Sheet1")).Name = "RawData"
   'ActiveSheet.Name = filename
    On Error Resume Next
    With ActiveSheet
        C = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If C > 1 Then C = C + 1
        Set Target = .Cells(1, C)
        With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & path & filename, _
                              Destination:=Target)
            .Name = filename
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = False
            .AdjustColumnWidth = False
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = xlWindows
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = vbTab
            .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
            .TextFileThousandsSeparator = " "
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Everything remains same as before but the newly imported file will be written to the next free cell in row 1.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for helping me! Your code works but  i would like to paste the data in the sheet named "data" instead at the import button sheet. How do i  do so? I did used the line "Sheets.Add(After: = Sheets("Sheet1")).Name = "RawData"" but it does not work

Comment: Just replace the line `With ActiveSheet` with `With Worksheets("RawData")`. The worksheet must exist. If you want it to be created in case it doesn't exist please ask another question. It isn't difficult but it's another topic.

Comment: Hi, i have changed with ActiveSheet to Worksheets("RawData") but now i faced with the same problem such the data from the 2 files was not imported to the respective columns.

Comment: It's `With Worksheets("RawData")`, have you got the `With`? Where does the code import the data to? Do you get an error message? The code works fine with me. The Query remembers the details of the last import. Perhaps you need to delete the query after changing the destination sheet. If you want me to trouble-shoot on your behalf you should supply a very precise description of your experience. "Same problem" is really not enough to understand what's happening on your PC.

Comment: I did placed a with. While using ActiveSheet, it paste the code to sheet1 where the import file button is at. I did not receive any error message.When i used With worksheets("rawdata"), it didnt show all 4 columns of the data from 2 imported file

Comment: At the rawdata sheet, it only show 1 set of data from a file

Comment: Sorry, I can't replicate your error. I now tested with 2 files and it works as expected.

Comment: Now, when i run the original code with "With ActiveSheet", i get one data set from a file only. Why is it so? Is it because how i select my file? While selecting my file, i use control function to select 2 file at once to import it? Am i doing it correctly?

Comment: No. It shouldn't matter how you select the files but trouble shooting should indeed start with the loop. Place `Debug.Print path, filename` there and see if all selected files are processed. Another telltale is that if all files are processed but only 2 columns shown these 2 columns should show the data from the last file processed.

Comment: I did that and found out that only 1 file is being imported at once despite me pressing 2 files at once. How can i import 2 files?

Comment: This is about your file selection procedure `ImportFiles` now and therefore unrelated to your original question. I tested and used your procedure without problem. Ask a new question, "Why can't I select more than one file with this code?" We can't find an answer to that here in the comments.